# Having Summary Page for Moderator Candidate in Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election, election-page, summary

As a new member in **Stack Overflow**, I am interested in following (listening, reading, observing) the **2014 Moderator Election**.

However, when I see the candidate information page, I personally got an similar pattern of Q&A page.

This is my personal impression related to these page:

1. http://elections.stackexchange.com/#stackoverflow

   or
2. https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1

My point is that we should scroll down to see the other candidate. We should go through all the statistic (in page 1) and or previous discussion (in page 2) before we get the whole image of the candidacy.

In my opinion, **it would be better if we have a summary page of candidacy**. This summary page will give the Stack overflow member a big picture of who is going for the candidate and shot info about them.

Comment: Usually, people would try to search for someone they know if there is a summary page. I think the current form might be good, since it forces us to look at all the candidates and their statements before looking at their statistics.

Comment: For election `Statistics` of the reviews is only needed.  Not there summary, if you're interested then check their profile.

Comment: nhahtdh and Praveen Thanks for the responses

Comment: Lets don't be open, but might be this is an example page: http://oscar.go.com/nominees

Comment: Can you describe a bit more what you're asking for? I'm not sure I follow. Note that on the first site you can remove the nomination text by clicking "None" in the topbar.

Comment: @TimStone I just try it. It is very helpful. We can see the summary of candidacy.

Comment: @TimStone He's asking for a page that basically lists all the candidates first and a quick short data bit, *then* there's the full actual nominations. In short, an overview of who is in the election just to know "Who is in there" first before diving into the specifics of their speeches and the like.

Comment: @GraceNote Hm, yeah, I suppose the statistics site could have an even more compact view, possibly by default, with a more direct option to expand the details for specific candidates.

Comment: @GraceNote and all. There is no limit to dream. This is just an idea. maybe we can realize it now or later, it is just the matter of time. Thank you you all and for your concern